# Sounds > Recording devices - freezes

Tags: windows-8, audio

I am using Windows 8 and I have a common Realtek audio chip.

Whenever I try to go to the recording devices tab, the tab freezes and I can't have access to it. All my audio drivers are updated.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you updated your chipset too?

Comment: Solution: I just did.

Comment: Eh? Sorry, is this still faulty or did it solve it?

Comment: I uninstalled the chipset driver, rebooted, the Win 8-Welcome tour started, after that I rebooted again and then it worked.

Comment: Ok, moved comment to an answer

Answer (score 2):

Update your drivers on your machine, including both audio and chipset drivers